# How to expose web service in Tibco BusinessEvents4

Tags: tibco

How to expose Tibco Business Events4.0 Concrete WSDL after deployed in Tibco admin??

I have implemented web services using Tibco Business Events. I am having a problem to expose concrete WSDL to clients.

How to expose concrete wsdl to clients in Tibco BE?(In Tibco BW we have to use retrieve resources or inbuilt configuration of service pallet).

Thanks so much!!